# Except joining 20 tables any other options for writting / reading data?

Tags: database-design, social-networking

I am creating a user profile. All the fields are lookup based from their own tables like favourite movies, favourite music, favourite food, sports, etc... These are not text fields but auto suggest fields from a system maintained list. The reason these are all in their own table is they have more colunms unique to them.

So to read the data at user input it is ok but after that two problems:
1) Writting data: Since this is a M:M relationship i will need 20 different tables?
2) Reading data at profile load time: I need to join all these 20 tables to get the user's data?

What other option do i have to store all these user details? my only concern is performance since this is a social site. 20 joins is not good. But i am not sure about other techniques. I am using mysql and php.

The only other option i can think of is to store the data in an array in the db although i dont know how well searches will work with that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install your favorite dbms.
2. Create a user table, and two or
   three user favorites tables.
3. Write a little program to generate
   and load a million random users.
4. Write a little program to generate
   and load 10 million favorite movies
   (or whatever) for those million
   users.
5. Run some queries.

If speed is a problem, post the schema with the "database-design" and "query-optimization" tags, and include a link to this question.

---

**Later . . .**
Bored. So I did the test myself. I don't have time to do 20 joins, but 5 left joins, on a table of a million users and 50+ million rows in each of the joined tables returns in about 400 milliseconds. (PostgreSQL 9.0.2) Back to work now . . .

---

**And still later . . .**
Still bored. I added more tables, more data, more left outer joins. Depending on the data for a particular email address, more joins can be still faster. (Would you have guessed that?) The last test I ran, selecting a few dozen random email addresses from "users",

```
           run time (milliseconds)
--
median      40 
maximum    222
minimum      0.4 ("Four tenths of a millisecond", not a typo.)
```

If I'm still bored later, I'll bang together a program to

- execute a few hundred queries based
  on random email addresses, and
- record the execution time (although I'm not sure that's possible)

Answer (score 0):

> 20 joins is not good

Who says? I wouldn't worry about the number of joins in your queries unless you see that it actually becomes a problem. Relational databases are *designed* to work around, well, relating tables to one another.

Now, as to whether or not you actually *need* 20 joins is another question entirely. You should post a sample query and some relevant portion of your database design and we can tell you if anything looks amiss.

Comment: The design is just fields that are M:M, each in their own table with an ID and name for now. Like (fav_brands, fav_places, fav_food, fav_drinks, fav_movies, fav_music, fav_sportteams, fav_sports, fav_activities, ...) And then there is user_brands, user_place, user_food, etc.. table to hold the user info which has 4 columns: id, user_id, created_dt, updated_dt.  As a thought i am thinking of adding 'name' also so the text description is also in the table of the item that way i don't have to query it up.

Comment: @SuriP: That's a perfectly sensible schema. Are you having issues with it? No relational database should have any problem serving up data like that virtually instantaneously.

Comment: No but the sample schemas i have seen on the net try to dump all user info into 1 table for a quick load. I dont want to use 20 tables for profile details if that is not the way it works in the real world.

Comment: @SuriP: In the real world (with real relational database systems), people normalize their data like you have it. Go with what you have.

Answer (score 0):

You could store user profiles in a non-relational data store like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org).

Not only will this avoid the mess of joins, but it makes it easier to change your user profile schema on the fly, and avoid writing a lot of data access code.

Comment: Well, then someone has to learn this database first. My dev team has never ventured out of MySQL so if they use this then they will spent a month trying to learn it which means a month lost for launch time.

Comment: I see a lot of people on the bandwagon of recommending NoSQL databases like MongoDB or CouchDB. I haven't messed with them, but I get the general idea behind a schemaless data store (even if I don't really get how not having a well-defined storage format is a *good* thing). How would using MongoDB or the like reduce the complexity of his query in this scenario?

Comment: @Adam All user profile data for one user would be held in a single 'document' (to use MongoDB terminology). You don't need any joins - you simply store and retrieve an object graph which contains all your data - eg. user preferences, favorite food, movies etc.

Comment: Can users do advanced searches / filters using these? And what about data analytc?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your performance requirements, 20 joins might or might not be a problem.  But if you want sub-second response under load, then it could indeed be good to avoid this. But if this only occurs when a user logs in, and you expect no more than a few logins per second, and you don't have other heavy db load, etc., then the performance might be quite tolerable.

I'd be surprised if you couldn't combine some of those.  I'd think that many of the profile attributes could be represented in a common structure like
PersonId, TraitType, string1, string2, int1, int2, date1, date2.

If, in your code, you are doing anything like an OO representation of your data then you could map the traittypes to classes that fully represent the type, so your program could would not need to work at  level of abstraction that this table design represents.

- Elroy

Comment: They are all different items, like how can you combine a user's Favourie Brand, Movie, Sport team, Activity, Music, Musician, etc. Each data has its own lookup table with its own set of properties. Otherwise I need to have 1 big lookup table to hold all these data and then have a seperate link table to link the big table to each individual table if i need the unique data of any item.

Comment: Assuming that the tables as they stand now have the proper foreign keys in place, then what you're proposing (a general-purpose "attribute" table, which essentially represents EAV) would actually be significantly *slower*. More *small* tables is preferable to fewer *large*, sparsely-populated tables. 20 joins on primary keys should cost next to nothing.

Comment: It is not joins that will matter but table size. If there are a million users, each user has 10 favorite movies so table is 10 million rows. Now each table (movies, sports, food, etc) will be give/take the same size. So system has to lookup the user_id, find all his favourites from each of these tables instantly on page load so it appears with his profile data.

Comment: Table size doesn't matter as much as you think it does. Indexing matters. Years ago, I demonstrated litigation support databases having 2 million rows, and results returned in about 250 msec. Using Microsoft Access 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to load ALL the data at profile load? It seems to me that your reference table NAMES represent some sort of affordances on the Profile itself which, when activated by the user, execute the query for items from that table, no?

I am not the expert web programmer, so I could have this all wrong. But it seems like the profile loads and presents the user with what amounts to a summary/navigation interface, right? With some buttons/glyphs what have you by which the user navigates and/or requests more information.

On profile load, the top-level profile info appears, along with (much over-simplified) some buttons, possibly under a header widget, "My Favorites". Buttons might exist for "PLaces", "Food/Drink", "Music", Etc. When the user activates one of THESE, a query executes against that particular table (and any relevant joins) to return the data specific to "Places" for example.

Maybe it is different with Web (and I will be learning soon enough), but I try to request data when it makes sense, and at a pont when the user might expect a brief access time. A button click is usually a point at which the user will expect a slight lag in response.

Comment: It is like your facebook profile, where you have favourite movies, sport teams, etc. Except facebook has maybe 10-15 fields of data. i have about 30-35 fields total. Ofcourse all wont load on page load, the UI is load one line of rows for each and have the user click 'more' to view more

Comment: OK, I get it. In that case, since you are already creating the joins in order to retreive that firt row for each, you might consider allowing most of any delay to be associated with the profile load. Experiment with how much MORE of the data can be effectively cached during the initial load sequence (when the page opens on the web, most folks expect a reasonable delay), and then load the first row for display. In that scenario, the greater lag at the front will be offset by much faster access once the user clicks to see "more". Compare to requesting as needed, and see which method  . . .

Comment: . . .results in a more satisfying user experience. Note that when FB or Myspace load, there is a sometimes considerable wait while the page loads. And then more wiating when you click on "View Photos" or what have you. Not being as familiar with some of the mechanics involved in the Web aspect of things, I guess I am less than helpful. But I do enjoy this type of problem! My last comment would be that maybe your dev team does the best you can for v1 as described above, and then preps for a re-working for v2 using Hadoop or MongoDb, which I believe were created for this very reason. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

One way to cut down on the number of joins is to store the data that is common to all 20 types in a single table.  The relationship of this table to the 20 specialized tables follows the gen-spec design pattern.  Lookup "generalization specialization relational modeling" to see how to implement the gen-spec pattern in tables.

If you do this, you will only reference the specialized tables when you need them.

I'm not sure of your usage patterns in your case, so I can't say if this advice applies to your situation.  But it's worth looking into.